# Unresolved reference: setSpan in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to set symbol * at mandatory field. for that i can use below code line:

```
hint_mobile!!.setText(Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.mobile_number) + "<sup> * </sup>"));
```

it is work but i can't set the red color at this symbol *

So i use another example like below :

```
hint_mobile!!.setText(resources.getString(R.string.mobile_number))
        val str = hint_mobile!!.text.toString()
        val loc = hint_mobile!!.text.toString().indexOf("*")
        str!!.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), loc, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

All code set grate but error come on below line:

```
str!!.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), loc, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

**ERROR**

```
Unresolved reference: setSpan
```

So How to i resolve this error ??

Comment: `str` is a `String`. The `String` class has no `setSpan` method. You can resolve this error by calling `setSpan` on the correct object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SpannableString, something like this:

```
val spannableString = SpannableString("${resources.getString(R.string.mobile_number)} *")
val loc = spannableString.toString().indexOf("*")
spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), loc, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
hint_mobile!!.setText(spannableString.toString())
```

Comment: if i use your code then it's give me a error like : **`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.addcontectdetail/com.addcontectdetail.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... 1) starts before 0`**

Comment: Because 'loc' value is -1, that mean he didn't found '*' inside your  hint_mobile textview

Comment: Okay i got it Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

@Alex code work but there is you want to set the position where to show **`*`**. So I can use below code. It is show the symbol **`*`** at end of the `String`.

```
        var simple : String? = resources.getString(R.string.mobile_number)

        var colored : String?  = " *"

        var builder = SpannableStringBuilder()

        builder.append(simple)
        var start = builder.length
        builder.append(colored)
        var end = builder.length

        builder.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        hint_mobile!!.setText(builder);
```